# pop specific fragment from stack and remove others

Tags: android, stack, fragment

how I can pop specific fragment from stack and remove others from a fragment?
for example these are my fragments and I'm in E right know.

A-> B -> C -> D ->E

wanna back from E to B and Clear C and D.
How I can do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add a tag to each fragment while adding them to the backstack and then popfragment from backstack till the fragment with the tag you want is not reached.

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

for (int i = fm.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (!fm.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(tagname)) {
        fm.popBackStack();
    }
    else
    {
     break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is called from the activity which hosts the fragments, doesnot work.

Answer (score 10):

You can call the function below while you are in `Fragment E`:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack("tag", 0);
```

Here the `tag` is string passed as tag while adding `fragment B` to `backstack`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using AndroidX navigation, you can use the following:

```
findNavController().popBackStack(R.id.FragmentB, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code for pop back stack entry:

```
 FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {

        fm.popBackStack();

    }else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**tldr: try using fragmentManager instead of supportFragmentManager if the code doesn't work**

**solution: `fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(tagName, 0)`**

I know it's an old question but after spending a few hours on this, I wasn't able to get close to the desired result.

I was using supportFragmentManager and the code was:

`supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(tagName, 0)`

but it wasn't working as intended neither according to what was written in the documentation.
Just as a fluke I thought about using the fragmentManager instead of the supportFragmentManager and voila, it worked!

So for anyone stuck on this, maybe give this a try.