# remove a specific fragment transaction from back stack

Tags: android, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I have a fragment manager that has more than one fragment transaction in it. Lets say transactions inside fragment manager is like A->B->C->D->E->F->G. Is there a way that i can pop a specific transaction in back stack ex frag C. I want to pop only one transaction and keep others transactions with same queue.

popBackStack() methods are not covering my case?

Is there anyone who has faced an issue like this?

Comment: Please go through the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852930/pop-specific-fragment-from-stack-and-remove-others

Comment: I tried all answers in that post. None of them worked for me

Comment: use popBackStack(string, int)

Answer (score 0):

When committing transactions you need to use tags.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.mainContainer, fragment, tag).addToBackStack(tag).commit();
```

Then you'll be able to remove it with this tag;

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.remove(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag)).commit();
```

Comment: This code removes the fragment but transactions still remains